# application.rb defined methods not being found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config

I'm working on a project where I've inherited some legacy code from an old version of Rails (1 or 2, I think). After tinkering with it, I tried starting it up, but I'm running into trouble in one of my controllers. Specifically, the line `@user = current_user || User.new`is stating that current_user can't be found. After doing some digging, I see that `def current_user` is hanging out in my application.rb file. Why isn't the app loading this method?

Am I misunderstanding how application.rb is supposed to work?

(If it matters, this method seems to be protected, but I don't know how that would prevent the app from seeing this definition.)

Comment: Hard to say without more context. You're probablt either not defining the method on the class you think you are or you're using it somewhere unexpected. Also ApplicationController used to be special cased to application.rb (instead of application_controller.rb) - not sure when it stopped loading the former

Comment: Thanks Frederick--your answer, in a very roundabout way, actually led to the answer.

You're right, there are apparently two application.rb files. I actually am the third group to inherit this code. The first was godly, and managed to write the entire thing. The second tried to update the app for new versions of Rails, and miserably failed.

They didn't notice that there were two different application.rb files and managed to SWITCH the files between the app/controllers and the config folders. I have no words...I feel just as stupid for not realizing this was what was going on.

Comment: Oh, and as a happy ending, I've switched the files and properly renamed the application.rb in the controller folder to application_controller.rb.  Everything is working now...so far.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments to the original question.